# One button to toggle slide div right and left

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I need one button to slide a div right and left. Code I've got below that's not working (or needs improving):

```
<div class="nav-btn">Button</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".nav-btn").click(function(){
            if($("#nav").css("left") <="70%") 
                {
               $("#nav").animate({left:'70%'});        
                }   
             else   {
            $("#nav").animate({left:'-70%'});      
                        }   
       }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("#nav").css("left")` will return the position in pixels. Therefor your function won't work.

I would recommend to use `toggleClass()` for this situation. Combined with CSS transition:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".nav-btn").on('click', function () {
        $('#nav').toggleClass('goLeft');
    });
});
```

```css
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
#nav.goLeft {
    left: -70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">a</div>

<div class="nav-btn">Button</div>
```